# Python - I can't stop the program running

Tags: python

I am completely new to python. I have installed it on windows. I am having a problem, I write:

```
from pylab import*

subplot(111,projection="hammer")

show()
```

After this it will not let me do anything else and ctrl-c does not work. I have looked at another post here and tried ctrl-break, ctrl-z and various other methods to no avail. Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/). It brings a matplotlib/pylab mode that handles all this for you. After you install IPython, you can start it with the `pylab` flag:

```
$ ipython -pylab
```

Then, in the interactive shell, you type your code:

```
In [1]: from pylab import*

In [2]: subplot(111,projection="hammer")
Out[2]: <matplotlib.axes.HammerAxesSubplot object at 0x2241050>

In [3]:
```

IPython automatically shows the plot using a separate thread and returns control to the interactive shell.

The documentation of [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/shell.html) has a little more information on how all this works.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple matter of interrupting a running program, have you tried CTRL-D ?

Comment: This still didn't work and so I downloaded ipython as above. Thank you for your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

After all of your imports for pylab and what not.. add:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

This will cause CTRL-C to not be caught by anything in your program, which should then cause it to kill the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching `KeyboardInterrupt` like so:

```
try:
    show()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Shutting down."
    import sys
    sys.exit()
```